# Jquery, the on click is triggered before even clicking on the button

Tags: jquery

I am new to jquery and I wrote a method like

```
function method(mess){
   alert('Hello '+mess);
}
$('#button').click(method('world'));
```

But every time I refresh the page it is being executed without even being clicked. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
function method(mess){
   alert('Hello '+mess);
}
$('#button').click(function(){
     method('world')
});
```

Your code is behaving that way because you are calling the function method('world') without listening for the click event.

You can see the difference between them on [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/34xzg7e9/5/).

Comment: Did you check the existing answer before posting this one?

Answer (score 3):

You are not using this correctly.

When you wrote `$('#button').click` what you actually did was triggering the `click` event on that element, and regardless - you called the `method('world')` function.

This is how it should look:

```
function method(mess){
   alert('Hello '+mess);
}

$('#button').on('click', function() { method('world') });
```